# How to make each picture and its paragraph sideways instead of vertical?

Tags: html, css

Both the images and their paragraphs are arranged neatly when being faced vertically, but I'm not sure how to make them face horizontally without messing it up. When I try to do it, the content messes up horribly.

```css
  body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 600px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 98.5%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: -30%;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul>li>.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.4em;
}

.navbar .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: teal;
}

.navbar>ul>li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button1 {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

footer {
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  align-it
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="banner-home">
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosmetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
      <button1>Login</button1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="cosmetics-header">
    <h1>Cosmetics</h1>
    <p> Choose from a wide variety of cosmetics, made to spark the beauty inside you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cosmetics-content">
    <div class="nail-polish">
      <p>Best Se​lling!</p>
      <img src="nail_polish.jpg" width="200" height="200">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><b>Nail Polish</b></p>
      <p>Choose from a wide variety of colors, guaranteed to last long and easily removable.<br>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="lipstick.jpg">
      <div>
        <p><b>Lipstick</b></p>
        <p> Highly pigmented lip color with a creamy smooth glide during application that leaves lips feeling hydrated, nurtured, and conditioned.<br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="brush.jpg" alt="" data-image-width="500" data-image-height="500">
    <div>
      <p><b>12pcs Brush Set</b></p>
      <p> Containing 12 high quality and durable make-up brushes.<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul class="socials">
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Clownehara" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012662688022" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/satrianavito/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <p>Copyright Ⓒ 2022 [Muhammad Vito Ananda Satriana]. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I tried using display flex but the result is messy like the pictures and paragraphs are merged.

Comment: Please check the validity of your HTML; there's at least one unclosed `<div>` element, in the `<footer>`. Also, what pictures should be horizontal? With what text? Is this really the "minimal* (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code required to demonstrate your problem, because I don't believe we need the whole document in order for your to show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

since no one is actually helping I will. Firstly there were alot of problems with your html. The number of div containers was not equal that's why whenever you tried the float property it would never work quite right. second tip if you're going to use divs instead of semantic html you should try to add class name on as many important elements you can think. so for containers, cards, card headers etc. or you can just use semantic html. anyway heres the answer code to your problem:
HTML:

```
`<section class="cosmetics-header">
    <h1>Cosmetics</h1>
    <p> Choose from a wide variety of cosmetics, made to spark the beauty inside you.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="cosmetics-content">
    <figure class="nail-polish">
      <p>Best Se​lling!</p>
      <img src="nail_polish.jpg" width="200" height="200">
      <figcaption>
       <h2>Nail Polish</h2>
      </figcaption>
      <article>
              <p>Choose from a wide variety of colors, guaranteed to last long and easily removable.</p>
      </article>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="lipstick.jpg">
      <figcaption>
        <h2>Lipstick</h2>
      </figcaption>
      <article>
         <p> Highly pigmented lip color with a creamy smooth glide during application that leaves lips feeling hydrated, nurtured, and conditioned.</p>
      </article>
    </figure>
    <figure>
          <img src="brush.jpg" alt="" data-image-width="500" data-image height="500">
      <figcaption>
        <h2>12pcs Brush Set</h2>
      </figcaption>
      <article>
       <p> Containing 12 high quality and durable make-up brushes.</p>
      </article>
    </figure>
  </section>
</div>`
```

I redid your HTML with proper semantics, hope thats okay, this way it's easier to target specific elements and it helps with SEO and google bots. Just replace your entire cosmetics section with that code and for
CSS:

```
`
  figure, figure *{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
figure img{
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
}
figure{
  clear: both;
  padding: 1em;
}`
```

Just add this bit to you CSS code it's fine, it will mix in perfectly and it will deal with the floating and positioning of your the figure elements. if you have any question hit me up and I'll gladly help you further or explain more if you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use flex position to align your image with your text.
I used this class `nail-polish` for all your block of image + text as a parent element :

```
.nail-polish {
  display: flex; // Will align your children elements
  margin: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem; // space between your children elements
}
```

You can also use `align-self: center` to center your text vertically with your image

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  height: 600px;
}

.navbar {
  width: 98.5%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  outline: none;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar .dropdown {
  display: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: -30%;
  outline: none;
}

.navbar ul li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.navbar>ul>li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar>ul>li>.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.4em;
}

.navbar .dropdown li {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: teal;
}

.navbar>ul>li::after {
  content: '';
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: teal;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.navbar>ul>li:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
}

button1 {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

footer {
  height: auto;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  align-it
}

.nail-polish {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.vertical-center {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>MediCare</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Products.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<div class="banner-home">
  <div class="navbar">
    <img src="icon.png" class="logo">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Healthcare</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cosmetic</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Misc.</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://127.0.0.1:3000/Project/AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none;">
      <button1>Login</button1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="cosmetics-header">
    <h1>Cosmetics</h1>
    <p> Choose from a wide variety of cosmetics, made to spark the beauty inside you.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cosmetics-content">
    <div class="nail-polish">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" width="200" height="200">
      <p>Best Se​lling!</p>

    </div>
    <div class="nail-polish">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200">
      <div class='vertical-center'>
        <p><b>Nail Polish</b></p>
        <p>Choose from a wide variety of colors, guaranteed to last long and easily removable.<br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nail-polish">

      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
      <div class='vertical-center'>
        <p><b>Lipstick</b></p>
        <p> Highly pigmented lip color with a creamy smooth glide during application that leaves lips feeling hydrated, nurtured, and conditioned.<br>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="nail-polish">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200" alt="">
    <div class='vertical-center'>
      <p><b>12pcs Brush Set</b></p>
      <p> Containing 12 high quality and durable make-up brushes.<br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div>
    <ul class="socials">
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Clownehara" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100012662688022" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/satrianavito/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="footer-content">
      <p>Copyright Ⓒ 2022 [Muhammad Vito Ananda Satriana]. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</footer>

</html>
```